# Does Re-Scraping URL for Facebook Open Graph affect Link/Share Ranking?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Occasionally writers on our news site want to change the Open Graph image associated with their Share link on Facebook, but they are concerned that re-scraping a link to update Open Graph data will hurt the link's ranking in Facebook's ranking algorithm (or worse, reset their like/share counts).  Does anyone know for sure that re-scraping does not affect rank/share counts? Thank you!

Comment: The algorithm is not public, so anyone can only speculate. But it would make little sense IMHO to have that “hurt” the ranking. And it definitively doesn’t reset like/share counts. // Older posts on Facebook will still show the old image though. If those should be updated as well, then the post owner has to trigger that manually via the UI.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts CBroe, I tend to agree. And ty for info about link/share count.